# AngularFire2, snapshot.val returns undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to log the value of 'Checker' (boolean) but it always returns 'undefined'. My code is below:

```
  loginUser(key: string, Checker: boolean) {
   if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
   *doesn't matter*
   } else {
   *doesn't matter*
   ...
    var checked = this.af.object('/Users/' + key, 
    {preserveSnapshot: true});
    checked.subscribe(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.key);
        console.log(snapshot.val.Checker);
      });
   }
```

Output on the console is:

```
*key*
*undefined*
```

Comment: `val` is a function: `snapshot.val().Checker`

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val

Comment: @cartant - If I do that, it returns "snapshot.val is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
this.af.object(`/users/${key}`, {preserveSnapshot: true})
  .subscribe( snapshot => {
  let value = snapshot.val()
  let key = snapshot.key
```

Note the use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can use backticks(template literals) inside of the .object() call to insert variables directly. You should read through the [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#meta-fields-on-the-object) documentation.